# Unable to render users list with Meteor + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm new to React and been struggling a lot at rendering a list of users for a simple user management table I'm trying to build. If anyone is able to see where I went wrong with this it would be greatly appreciated if you could let me know as I've been spending a ton of time on it and reading everything I could find but still have had no success.

I've tried many different variations but this is what I currently have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ManageUsers extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
}
renderUsers() {
  return this.props.users.map((users) => {
    return <ManageUsers key={users._id} user={users}/>;
  });
};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>{this.renderUsers()}</li>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ManageUsers.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe("users");
  return {
  users: Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()
  }
})(ManageUsers);
```

I receive a few different errors with this in my browser console including:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `users` is marked as required in
> `ManageUsers`, but its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Either test that `users` is defined before mapping, or give it a default prop value.

```
renderUsers = () => {
  const { users } = this.props;
  return users && users.map(user => <ManageUsers key={user._id} user={user}/>);
};
```

or

```
ManageUsers.defaultProps = {
  users: [],
};
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop users is marked as required in  ManageUsers, but its value is undefined.

This usually means that although it's a required prop you probably aren't passing it defined data from the parent component.

In this case, it appears the Meteor HOC isn't providing the `users` data when the react component is mounting.  I'm not familiar with Meteor, but perhaps you could make the subscribe function async, and await for it to resolve with a value for the `users` prop.

```
export default withTracker(async () => {
  Meteor.subscribe("users");
  return {
    users: await Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()
  }
})(ManageUsers);
```